# Using UPPER in ON clause of JOIN for Postgres 9.2.4

Tags: space, postgresql-9.2

When joining two tables on a varchar column wrapped in a upper statement, the join does not work if there is a trailing space in both of the varchar values.

In the two examples below, VALUE1 and VALUE2 = 'ABC '

-- Doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2
ON UPPER(VALUE1) = UPPER(VALUE2)
```

-- Works

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2
ON UPPER(TRIM(VALUE1)) = UPPER(TRIM(VALUE2))
```

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(value1 varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE table2(value2 varchar(10));
INSERT INTO table1 values('ABC ');
INSERT INTO table2 values('ABC ');

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2
ON UPPER(VALUE1) = UPPER(VALUE2)
```

Result:

```
 value1 | value2 
--------+--------
 ABC    | ABC
```

**It appears to work**.

Make sure you don't use the `CHAR(N)` type instead of `VARCHAR(N)`, since they have different semantics concerning spaces.